Limits of sequences of nonlinear "bounded" operators
I have a sequence of nonlinear operators $T_n\colon X \to Y$ between two separable Hilbert spaces. The operators are bounded uniformly in that there is a constant $C$ with
$$|T_n(x)| \leq C|x|.$$
I want to know something about the limit of $T_n$. Is it possible to formulate some compactness result in some operator norm for the $T_n$? In my particular case of $T_n$,I want to know what properties the limit $T$ has (if it exists).
Does anyone know any results for nonlinear operators like this?

If $L(X, Y)$ is finite-dimensional, there is a convergent subsequence. If not, there might not be.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend The OP’s asking about nonlinear operators. So this has nothing to do with $L(X, Y)$.

Except the completely trivial case $X = {0}$, the space (or rather, its norm unit ball) is basically never compact metrizable, so no, no such results can be formulated.

I misread for linear, sorry.
